Simple circuit to interface MCU digital input with external high voltage
I am trying to build a GPS Tracker (STM32F103 MCU based), where I need a feature to detect the vehicle's IGNITION status (On / Off). The vehicle's batteries are generally 12V or 24V. But to be on a safe site, I want to make sure that the input can handle up to 40V.
I should not load the vehicle's IGNITION line much and thus I want a circuit which has a big impedance and do the job that I need.
I am thinking to use a transistor to somehow isolate the external circuit from the MCU. As of now, I have come up with this simple voltage divider circuit, that switch on a transistor at around 8V.
I need to keep the power loss as less as possible.
Please note that, this really has to be simple circuit (no op-amp, opto or such).
I have tried simulating this on LTSpice and the result is attached. Wanted to have some feedbacks on this circuit and if there are errors that I am overlooking.



The 1MΩ resistance seems unnecessarily high - when the ignition is on there will be substantial draw from other stuff, and when it is off there will be zero draw. You're also dividing down the voltage, reducing the already meagre base current and making it less reliable. Depending on beta to control the switching voltage is not a good plan because beta varies with temperature and from unit to unit, and automotive applications generally require a wide temperature range.
Here is an alternative:

Note that your circuit requires almost 12V to switch at the low end of the automotive temperature range, and that's not even taking transistor variations into account.
Personally, I'd probably use a 1N751 because the cranking voltage can get quite a bit lower than 8V. Also I'd put a 1N4148 from base to emitter to limit the negative voltage at the base. I'd probably go down another order of magnitude in the resistor values too, I don't think 1mA amounts to a hill of beans in the crazy automotive world.

Here's a circuit that I've used in the past. The key issue is that in a motor vehicle, the electrical system can experience "load dumps" that can create ±200 V transients.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

R1 limits the input current to ±2 mA, but still provides 120 µA @ 12 V
C1 filters out glitches
D1 protects the B-E junction of Q1 from reverse voltages
R2 provides a pull-up current of 0.33 or 0.50 mA, which can be sunk by Q1 as long as it has a current transfer ratio of at least 30


Yes, this is also a solution. Thanks.
